# Series $q^{2k}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} q^{2k} = \frac{q^{2}}{1 - q^{2}}$, where $0<q<1$?

I gather that this sum is the limit to which a sequence of partial sums $\left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} q^{2k}  \right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges.

I verified numerically that $\frac{q^{2}}{1 - q^{2}}$ is indeed the answer here. How to show it?

I reckon it's a convergence type proof, where for any $\epsilon>0$ I must pick $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \implies \lvert \sum_{k=1}^{n} q^{2k} - \frac{q^{2}}{1 - q^{2}} \rvert < \epsilon$, but I fail to do it. I try to get there by fixing some $\epsilon$ and checking different $N$, but this isn't leading me to the solution.

Comment: Have you considered substituting $r = q^2$?

Comment: I didn't, ok I try that now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} q^{2k} = \frac {q^2 (1 - q^{2n} )} {1 - q^2},\ \text {for any}\ n \geq 1.$$ Also observe that $q^{2n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for $0 < q < 1.$

Comment: Thanks! I missed the first observation, it's clear now

Answer (score 2):

Prove by induction that $\frac{q^2}{1-q^2}-\sum_{k=1}^nq^{2k}=\frac{q^{2(n+1)}}{1-q^2}$. If $|q|<1$, this $\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.